# What happens if a TimerTask takes longer to execute than the specified interval?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

When using

`Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`

(i.e. with fixed-delay execution), what happens if the specified `TimerTask`'s `run()` method takes longer than `period` to complete? Is it possible that two concurrent `TimerTask` threads will be running because of this?
And if so, is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Timer's [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) says the following:

> Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes.

That is, concurrent `TimerTask` threads will not be running. The tasks will accumulate into a queue. This may or may not be appropriate (more likely, not).

Answer (score 20):

`Timer` and `TimerTask` don't handle this sort of situation well. If you want to handle it better, then don't use those classes.

[`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) provides two scheduling methods, [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) and [`scheduledWithFixedDelay`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29), which govern what happens when tasks "bunch up".

`scheduleAtFixedRate`:

> Creates and executes a periodic action
>   that becomes enabled first after the
>   given initial delay, and subsequently
>   with the given period; that is
>   executions will commence after
>   initialDelay then initialDelay+period,
>   then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so
>   on. If any execution of the task
>   encounters an exception, subsequent
>   executions are suppressed. Otherwise,
>   the task will only terminate via
>   cancellation or termination of the
>   executor. If any execution of this
>   task takes longer than its period,
>   then subsequent executions may start
>   late, but will not concurrently
>   execute.

`scheduleWithFixedDelay`:

> Creates and executes a periodic action
>   that becomes enabled first after the
>   given initial delay, and subsequently
>   with the given delay between the
>   termination of one execution and the
>   commencement of the next. If any
>   execution of the task encounters an
>   exception, subsequent executions are
>   suppressed. Otherwise, the task will
>   only terminate via cancellation or
>   termination of the executor.

You can create `ScheduledExecutorService` instances using the `Executors` factory class.

Comment: How is `scheduleAtFixedRate` better than `Timer` and `TimerTask`? Both ensure that the stuff happens at fixed intervals, and if the interval spills over to the next execution, the execution is queued.