# Java ScheduledExecutorService executing faster than intended

Tags: java, concurrency, fixed, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm currently having issues with a ScheduledExecutorService executing faster than the given timeframe.

[scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) states that subsequent executions may be late but it does not wait the given time afterwords.

GrabPutTask simply grabs information from a source, assigns the capture time, and sends it to a database. Because the interval becomes less than a second, the database entry gives an error in regards to a duplicate entry.

Is there a way to execute the task at a fixed time AFTER the previous task has completed?

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264476/what-happens-if-a-timertask-takes-longer-to-execute-than-the-specified-interval) that the tasks "bunch up" in a queue but a solution for my needs was not presented.

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //
    ..
    //
    //Creating the looping thread.
    try
    {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new GrabPutTask(), (long) 1, (long) (seconds * 1000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("DBUpdater connected and running. (GetAddr: %s, SetAddr: %s, Poll Rate: %.2f, Sector Number: %s, Number of PLCs: %d)",
                                  FROM_IP.split(":", 2)[0] + ":" + fromServer.getPort(), dataSource.getURL(), seconds, SECTOR, NUMBER_OF_PLCS_ON_MASTER));
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
    {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        printUsage();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Example execution time intervals:

```
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:07.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:08.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:09.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:10.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:11.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:12.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:13.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:14.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:15.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:16.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:17.199
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:19:18.199
...
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:20:21.415 (A load on the server it seems)
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:20:22.215
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:20:23.425
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:20:24.422
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:20:25.276
Event Called: 2014/02/12 14:20:25.997
```

Comment: Did you see the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` method right after that one?

Comment: @chrylis You should post that as an answer. It's far less bulky than my  `Thread.sleep()` answer.

Comment: @John It's not clear that that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry for not being clear. That's exactly what I was looking for! Please post as an answer and I'll + you. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

`scheduleWithFixedRate` tries to "catch up" if execution is delayed for whatever reason. You can use `scheduleWithFixedDelay` to keep the system from starting the clock until after the previous execution; delays will accumulate and won't catch up.

Answer (score 0):

To sleep for any amount of time.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(someTime);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```